# variance function on a mean polynomial (nlme R package)

Tags: r, polynomials, variance, nlme

I want to fit a variance function that involves polynomial terms of the mean

[image]

I know that I can fit the variance function

[image]

using `varExp()` (without arguments). Reading the documentation of `varExp()` it defaults to `~ fitted(.)`, however using `varExp(~ fitted(.))` gives an error, therefore `varExp(~ fitted(.)^2)` is not working.

Here is a code example in which I am working:

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(MASS)
p_load(nlme)
set.seed(123)
n<-1000

z0<-data.frame(days=runif(n,-3,3))

z0_mat <- model.matrix(~ days, z0)
betas<-c(10,.85)
a0<-1.5
b0<-8
b1<- -0.2
x_target<-60
alpha<-(log(b0)-log(a0))/x_target
z0$weight <- z0_mat%*%betas+rnorm(n,0,a0*exp(alpha*z0_mat[,2]+b1*z0_mat[,2]^2))
z0 %>% ggplot(aes(x=days,y=weight))+geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
m01<-gls(weight~days,weights=varComb(varExp(form=~days),varExp(form=~days^2)),data=z0)
intervals(m01,which = "var-cov")
#> Approximate 95% confidence intervals
#> 
#>  Variance function:
#>                lower        est.       upper
#> A.expon -0.007686726  0.01778161  0.04324994
#> B.expon -0.212892581 -0.19686001 -0.18082744
#> 
#>  Residual standard error:
#>    lower     est.    upper 
#> 1.394629 1.487835 1.587270
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

in `m01` I implemented a variance function on the covariate days,

[image]

but I would want to implement it on the mean. In this example this approach would be enough, however with more covariates in (the mean structure of) the model it would be better to use the mean rather than covariates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs without throwing an error

```r
v1  <- varComb(
    varExp(form=~fitted(.)),
    varExp(form=~I(fitted(.)^2)))
m01 <- gls(weight~days, weights= v1, data = z0)
```

- It is always confusing that `form` is not the first argument to the `var*` functions, thus `varExp(fitted(.))` doesn't do what you think it does ...
- I thought you would need the `I(...)` in the quadratic term, but apparently you don't ...
- However, the reported residual std error is vanishingly small — I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: are you sure about `variance = exp(b0*mu) + exp(b1*mu^2)` but not `variance = exp(b0*mu+b1*mu^2)`? documentation in `?varComb` says: "The corresponding variance function is equal to the product of the variance functions ...", also the estimation of the variance parameters are very close to the real parameters which I used to simulate, and they follow the product formula. I feel dumb because the main issue with my question was just solved by `form=~fitted(.)`.  thanks for that.

Comment: oh, you're right! That's nice.